# Expression not recognizing pointer in function c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, c++11, parameters

I have `class NumberArray` in `NumberArray.h`

```
class NumberArray
{
 private:
  double *aPtr;
  int arraySize;



public:
  NumberArray(NumberArray &);
  NumberArray(int size, double value);
  NumberArray() { if (arraySize > 0) delete[] aPtr; }
  void print() const;
  void setValue(double value);

};
```

In my cpp file, `NumberArray.cpp` I define the constructor

```
NumberArray(NumberArray &)
```

by

```
NumberArray::NumberArray(NumberArray &obj)
{
  arraySize = obj.arraySize();
  aPtr = new double[arraySize];
  for (int index = 0; index < arraySize; index++)
    {
      aPtr[index] = obj.aPtr[index];
    }
}
```

From all I've learned, this should work. However I'm receiving an error "expression preceeding parenthesis of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type.

I thought I already did have a point-to function type...

Can someone help me with where I went wrong?

Comment: BTW, if you use initializers for `aPtr` and `arraySize`, they can be made `const` (you'll probably want to declare them in the opposite order):  `NumberArray::NumberArray(NumberArray &obj) : arraySize(obj.arraySize), aPtr(new double[obj.arraySize])
{ ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arraySize = obj.arraySize();
```

`arraySize` is a class member. It is not a class method. This should be:

```
arraySize = obj.arraySize;
```

Comment: Baddabing baddaboom. New programmer, still don't know how I missed that one though -_-.

Thank you